# Magento 1 - Create own adminhtml theme (to override templates from adminhtml)

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, theme, design, extend

I need to override the file **app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml**.

What steps are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way:

1. `app/etc/config.xml`

   ```
   <config>
       <!-- We add this : Add "atome" admin theme-->
       <stores>
           <admin>
               <design>
                   <theme>
                       <template>atome</template>
                   </theme>
               </design>
           </admin>
       </stores>
   </config>
   ```
2. copy file from :

   ```
   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/design/adminhtml/default/atome/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml
   ```
3. Add your custom code in `default/atome/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml`

Comment: Can you add informations where you found out about this way, a link to the documentation for example?

Comment: I gave you a simple solution that works, it's clean and we don't udate the magento core files, now if that doesn't satisfy you, please ignore it. Good luck

Comment: Yes it works, but it is rather a hack, since you can't even provide an official source where it is described that we can do it like this.

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as a hack. In fact he's using a Magento override mechanic that is put there for a purpose; `app/etc/config.xml` is there specifically to make config changes, just like `app/etc/local.xml` is there to make environment specific config changes. This way he simply configs a new theme to be loaded under the `admin` store, which is the correct way to do it without building a full module to change admin themes via a web-based toggle.

Comment: @Rhys-SproutDesk exactly, you understood why I posted this solution, this is why I indicated "The simple way" right before I started the answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Rhys-SproutDesk, ok, but strange that we can't just change the adminhtml theme from the backend and that magento does not describe anywhere how this should be done correctly.